# Correctly stopping an autorun() function when template is destroyed

Tags: meteor

I have a template that contains a chart, rendered using MorrisJS. The chart should update when the `currentData` session variable is changed, so I have made it a reactive data source with:

```
Template.chart.rendered = function() {

    var template = this;

    Deps.autorun(function(c) {

        // Stop if the template is removed from the dom
        // Q: Is this really right?
        if(template.__component__.dom.parentNode() === null) {
            c.stop();
            return;
        }

        var results = Session.get('currentData');

        // ... render a chart with `results` as the data

        Morris.Bar({element: template.$(".chart-container"), data: results, ...});

    });

};
```

Notice how I do a fairly horrid check for when to stop the autorun above. This was necessary because without this, when I navigate away from the page using the template (I'm using `iron-router`) to another page and back, I get warnings in the log like "Can't select in removed DomRange". I'm pretty sure this is happening because the template instance is removed, but the autorun is still running.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here, though. Is there (a) a better place to put the autorun so that it doesn't have this problem or (b) a better way to stop the computation when the template instance is removed from the DOM?

I tried to find a way to do it with `created` and `destroyed` handlers, but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 6):

`Tracker.autorun` returns a handle that you can store as a template instance property, then call its `stop` method in the `onDestroyed` lifecycle event.

```
Template.chart.onRendered(function(){
  this.computation = Tracker.autorun(function(){...});
});

Template.chart.onDestroyed(function(){
  this.computation.stop();
});
```

EDIT 29-09-2014

In newer versions of Meteor (0.9 onward), there is a new `autorun` function available on template instances which provide simpler code to achieve the same result : no need to store and stop the computation manually, this is taken care of by the framework.

```
Template.chart.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(function(){...});
});
```

Comment: In keeping with your approach with destroyed, store the reference for the computation when it's provided as the autorun callback argument (as opposed to obtaining it from the return value of Deps.autorun)

Comment: @matb33 - why do you say that? The solution from saimeunt seems to work (I thought it didn't at first, but the error I saw was a red herring).

Comment: In new Meteor I still want to stop autorun and start again, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

With the new autorun

```
Template.chart.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(function(computation){
    ...
    computation.stop();
  });
});
```

but with this autorun, when chart template is removed from the DOM it is removed automatically.
This is in Meteor documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun):

> The Computation is automatically stopped when the template is destroyed.